# Duplicate values from Firebase loaded into ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that involves messaging people and whenever I load a message from a childeventlistener to add to the listview the message/object in the list view appears twice, I don't see whats causing that to happen? Every time a message is sent I call a method that adds it to the adapter and then I use the notifiyDataSetChanged() method to add it onto the list view as if it was a normal messaging app.

My Chat activity:

```
chatURLRoot.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public String chat_msg, chat_username;

    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            chatList.add(chat);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

chatListAdapter:

```
public class chatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> {

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    TextView usernameTV, messageTV;

    public chatListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Chat> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String username = getItem(position).getUsername();
        String message = getItem(position).getMessage();

        Chat chat = new Chat(username, message);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);


        usernameTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_chat);
        messageTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_chat);

        usernameTV.setText(username);
        messageTV.setText(message);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot,

Nathan

**Answer**:

I just had a massive brain surge, since the line of code to add the values to the listview was in the for loop, and there's two values that needed to be checked, it would run that line of code twice! Here's the updated code, I just put it oustide the for loop:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);


            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
        chatList.add(chat);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:
In My Chat activity, append_chat_conversation is changed.

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

        Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
        adapter.add(chat);
        Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
        Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```